# Cant' get a variable in buildscript section

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have a variable in build.gradle.kts file:

```
val foo by project
```

and can't get this variable inside buildscript {} section. 
Always get an error: Unresolved reference: foo

Somebody know how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: cany you post your build.gradle.kts code